Enrich.ExecutePolicy is not working in nest.dll elasticsearch
I am not able to execute the policy using nest.dll
var taskPolicy = client.Enrich.ExecutePolicy("mergeevent154",  x => x.WaitForCompletion(false));
Error,
FailureReason: Unrecoverable/Unexpected BadResponse while attempting PUT on http://localhost:19200/_enrich/policy/mergeevent154/_execute?wait_for_completion=false

[1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:19200/ Exception: JsonParsingException Took: 00:00:00.2527810
Audit exception in step 1 BadResponse:
Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonParsingException: expected:'{', actual:'400', at offset:299
at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonReader.ReadIsBeginObjectWithVerify()
at Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver )
at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Resolvers.DynamicMethodAnonymousFormatter1.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver) at Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver ) at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Resolvers.DynamicMethodAnonymousFormatter1.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)
at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)
at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)
at Nest.DefaultHighLevelSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)
at Elasticsearch.Net.DiagnosticsSerializerProxy.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)
at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.SetBody[TResponse](ApiCallDetails details, RequestData requestData, Stream responseStream, String mimeType)
at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.ToResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, Exception ex, Nullable1 statusCode, IEnumerable1 warnings, Stream responseStream, String mimeType)
at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
Inner Exception: expected:'{', actual:'400', at offset:299

